# Any Programming languages that can open and interact with Windows programs?

Tags: windows

I was recently thinking of learning a programming language that can interact with Windows Program?Is there any such thing that can do things like open Chrome,navigate to a webpage,Click some buttons,input something?
P.S -> Please don't suggest Imacros :)
I saw one program like that and wonder what programming language it is written in and can interact with programs?
Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an AppleScript equivalent for Windows.

Check out [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

The functionality you want is also available via COM.

Comment: Thanks.Finally Learned that and succeeded in creating what I wanted.Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Most programs that interact with the GUI of other running applications use the [Automation/Accessibility API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375.aspx)s built into windows. Take a look at linked overview page for details.

To answer the language part, anything that can call into those APIs will work (C++ and C# being fairly common for this purpose).

Comment: I know a little C++.I knew the CreateProcess function but didn't knew that you can interact with the program.
Thanks a lot.